# DH Keypair generation time on Android

Tags: android, time, nexus-one, diffie-hellman

This is the code that I'm using to generate a DH keypair:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
keyGen.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair ackp = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
```

(without the needed try/catch, of course).

I've done some tests running such code iteratively and varying the key size (in particular ramping up from 128 with a 128 step up to 1024. 1024 would be the desired size.

First of all, running each size generation 10 times to have some minimal std deviation on the results gives HIGH fluctuation of results, on average, anyway, the time needed for creating the keys (**1024 bit**) is: 683027ms, which rounds up to around **11 minutes** for creating a key.

The questions are:

1. Is anyone else getting the same results?
2. Is there some optimization to be run in order to achieve lower times?
3. What is the high fluctuation dependent of? (i.e. for generating a 1024bit key it can take from 18 seconds to 30 minutes...)

Tests have been run on a Nexus-One phone

Thanks in advance for shedding some light on the "issue"

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some further coding/research and apparently the call that's the most time (battery?) consuming is:

```
new SecureRandom()
```

In particular, though, since for DH the parameters (g, p, l) can be pre-computed and hard-coded it's a wise suggestion to do so beforehand and use the generated values to generate the key pair (which will be almost instantaneous).

Example code:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
keyGen.initialize(new DHParameterSpec(p, g, l));
KeyPair ackp = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
```

Where p, g, and l are:

```
final BigInteger p = new BigInteger("X");
final BigInteger g = new BigInteger("Y");
final int l = 1023;
```

And X and Y can be generated offline with:

```
AlgorithmParameterGenerator paramGen = AlgorithmParameterGenerator.getInstance("DH");
paramGen.init(1024, new SecureRandom());
AlgorithmParameters params = paramGen.generateParameters();
DHParameterSpec dhSpec = (DHParameterSpec)params.getParameterSpec(DHParameterSpec.class);
System.out.println("p: " + dhSpec.getP() + "\ng: " + dhSpec.getG() + " \nl: " + dhSpec.getL());
```

Comment: If you generate keys like this, It wont make your data any more secure than plain text.

Comment: I know its a bit late, but one downvote from me for the reason Behrooz pointed out. The randomness is crucial for security, re-use is not an option if you want to be secure. The actual issue with the timing may point to some issue with how your Android device collects entropy, it sounds like an issue with the platform to me.

Comment: I think the previous two comments are incorrect.  The parameters *p* and *g* are completely public in Diffie-Hellman; they are used to generate private information in the call to `generateKeyPair`.  You can see this at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Public_Key) and also in the lists of "well-known groups", which are recommended values for *p* and *g*, given in e.g. [RFC2539](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2539#appendix-A) and [RFC3526](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3526).