# How To Generate Parameter Set for the Diffie-Hellman Key Agreement Algorithm in Android

Tags: java, android, diffie-hellman

I am working on mobile/server security related project. I am now stuck in generating a Diffie-Hellman key agreement part. It works fine in server side program but it is not working in mobile side. Thus, I assume that it is not compactible with Android.

I used the following class to get the parameters. It returns a comma-separated string of 3 values. The first number is the prime modulus P. The second number is the base generator G. The third number is bit size of the random exponent L.

*My question is is there anything wrong with the code or it is not compactible for android?What kind of changes should I do?*
Your suggestion and guidance would be very much help for me. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
public static String genDhParams() {
 try {
// Create the parameter generator for a 1024-bit DH key pair
AlgorithmParameterGenerator paramGen = AlgorithmParameterGenerator.getInstance("DH");
paramGen.init(1024);
// Generate the parameters
AlgorithmParameters params = paramGen.generateParameters();
DHParameterSpec dhSpec = (DHParameterSpec)params.getParameterSpec(DHParameterSpec.class);
// Return the three values in a string
return ""+dhSpec.getP()+","+dhSpec.getG()+","+dhSpec.getL();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
} catch (InvalidParameterSpecException e) {
}
return null;
}
```

Regards,
*Sebby*

Comment: You cannot generate different domain parameters on each machine. Pick one set of domain parameters and use them everywhere. The domain parameters are not secret, and you can find suitable ones in various NIST and IETF publications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, GregS. Actually, I want those parameters to generate in mobile side. As it is not working, I tried it on server side and it is working. Thus I want to know whether the codes are not compactible with android.

Comment: umm.. it generates the three parameters in server side program. but in mobile side, the screen went black and nohing comes up. not even the former generated things such as nonce value, message sent from server side, etc.

Comment: Well, it could be something else in the program, plus how do you know you're not getting one of the exceptions you are swallowing.

Answer (score 0):

As revealed by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469235/dh-keypair-generation-time-on-android) DH parameter generation is incredibly slow on Android.  (That asker thought the culprit was generating a `new SecureRandom()`, but I find the slowness in `DHParametersGenerator.generateParameters()`, specifically its call to `java.math.BigInt.generatePrimeDefault()`.)

Moreover, that asker shows how to use pre-generated parameters.  The parameters can be fixed, and the key pair generator will still generate a new keypair each time.